# Probability of Punctures for a group of cyclists

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

The matter of the probability of punctures occurring cropped up during a ride yesterday with a friend.

His view is this, (As we can't let a subject drop....  ;-) )

"Eric,

There must be more chance of a puncture occurring if there are more riders.

The way I see it is this:

If there is a 20% chance of a rider getting a puncture, then that means there is a 1 in 5 chance of a puncture for that rider. As a fraction that is 1/5. It follows that if there were 5 riders, the chances would be 5/5 for the group (i.e., one puncture). It follows that if there were 10 riders it would be 10/5 which means there would be 2 punctures.

Therefore, the more riders there are, the more there is a chance of a puncture."

My view was that yes, 1/5 (20%) can be a figure to agree on, but that figure is stand alone, irrespective of the number of riders on the ride.

I know probability is very counter intuitive to the human mind, so what seems to be the case is not always the case.

Can anyone give a view, given that we're probably both high school grade mathematicians...if we're lucky!

Eric

Comment: Your friend is right: For a group of 10 cyclists, the [expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) of the total number of punctures is 2.

Comment: By $5$ riders $1$ puncture is to be "expected". This in the sense that if that $5$ riders do that a lot of times (let's say 1000 times) then there will be an average very close to $1$ puncture per time. But that is not the same as: there is a chance of $\frac55=1$ on a puncture each time. Their will be times with $0$ punctures, times with $1$, times with $2$ etc.

Comment: drhab - Thanks, I think you've captured what i was trying to express on the ride, namely that because there are more riders it doesn't necessarily mean that there will be a puncture, just there is more chance of it.

Answer (score 2):

The word "chance" is very loosely used in the question. Let's examine the case for 5 riders.

If it is the **expected** value that is sought, E[x] = np, so for  5 riders, $5\cdot\frac15 = 1$

If it is the **probability** that is sought,

P(none of the 5 have a puncture) = $(\frac{4}{5})^5 = \frac{1024}{3125}$

Thus P(at least one puncture occurs) = 1 - $\frac{1024}{3125} = \frac{2101}{3125},\approx 0.67$

Comment: Nope, can't follow the math at all, sorry!

e.g. 1024/3125....what are those figures and how have you arrived at them?

Comment: P(have a puncture) = 1/5. P(not have a puncture) = 1 - 1/5 = 4/5. P(2 people don't have a puncture) = $\frac{4\cdot4}{5\cdot5} = \frac{16}{25}$ by the multiplicative principle. Similarly, for 5 people, it becomes $\frac{4\cdot4\cdot4\cdot4\cdot4}{5\cdot5\cdot5\cdot5\cdot5}= \frac{1024}{3125}$.

Answer (score 1):

If there are $N$ riders, the probability of having no puncture is $$\Bbb{P}(\text{ no puncture }) = \bigg(\frac{4}{5}\bigg)^N $$

and that decreases with $N$. As the numbers of riders increase, the probability of occuring a puncture increases.

Answer (score 1):

This can be interpreted as a [Bernoulli process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_process). The probability of any *single* rider getting a puncture is (say) $1/5$. The probabilities of the different riders getting punctures are all independent, so to find the probability of certain people getting punctures, multiply $0.2$ for all the people who get punctures and $0.8$ for all the people who don't.

To have no punctures, multiply $0.8$ by itself for as many people as you have. It's less than $1$, so as you raise it to higher and higher powers, it gets smaller and smaller. That means as you have more and more people, your group has a smaller and smaller chance of escaping the trip unscathed.

You can find the exact formulas from the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

Comment: "The probability of any single rider getting a puncture is (say) 1/5. The probabilities of the different riders getting punctures are all independent."

Yep, the point I was trying to make, I think.....

Comment: @EricRichardson Right. The difference is the probability of a *single* person getting a puncture versus the probability of *someone in the group* getting a puncture.